# npyscreen - displaying the current time in a FixedText widget?

Tags: python, npyscreen

I'm trying to display the time in a FixedText widget in an NPSAppManaged application.

So far I've got this:

```
import npyscreen
import datetime
import threading
from time import sleep

class MainForm(npyscreen.Form):
    def create(self):
        self.add(npyscreen.FixedText, value = "Time")

    def afterEditing(self):
        self.parentApp.setNextForm(None)

    def set_value(self):
        return "Tom"

class TestApp(npyscreen.NPSAppManaged):

    def onStart(self):
        self.registerForm("MAIN", MainForm())

        thread_time = threading.Thread(target=self.update_time,args=())
        thread_time.daemon = True
        thread_time.start()

    def update_time(self):
       while True:
           # self.f.wStatus2.value = datetime.datetime.now().ctime()
           # self.f.wStatus2.display()
           sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = TestApp()
    App.run()
```

I'm just not sure how to reference the `.value` parameter for the widget from the thread and update it. What should I be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the `npyscreen.FixedText` to a variable as such:

```
 def create(self): 
     self.w_time = self.add(npyscreen.FixedText, value = "Time")
```

Now you can use `self.w_time.value` to access it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import npyscreen
import datetime
import threading
from time import sleep

class MainForm(npyscreen.Form):
    def create(self):
        self.date = self.add(npyscreen.TitleText, value = str(datetime.datetime.now()), editable=False, name='Something')

    def afterEditing(self):
        self.parentApp.setNextForm(None)

    def set_value(self):
        return "Tom"

class TestApp(npyscreen.NPSAppManaged):

    def onStart(self):

        self.textual = MainForm()
        self.registerForm("MAIN", self.textual)

        thread_time = threading.Thread(target=self.update_time,args=())
        thread_time.daemon = True
        thread_time.start()

    def update_time(self):
        while True:
            self.textual.date.value = str(datetime.datetime.now())
            self.textual.display()
            sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = TestApp()
    App.run()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).